# Regex matching uppercase characters with lowercase search

Tags: regex, notepad++, uppercase, lowercase

I'm using notepad++ and I'm finding that when I use regex to search for strings where I specifically want to find lowercase letters ("[a-z]") it will sometimes return uppercase letters.

I originally was searching using the string:

```
^[A-Z][a-z].+?$
```

With the purpose of deleting any line in my file that began with an uppercase character, followed by a lowercase, followed by anything until the end of the line. However, this returned lines like, "CLONE" and "DISEASE" which were only capital letters. Out of curiosity, I tried:

```
^[a-z].+?$
```

And it still returned those lines in all-caps. Finally, I tried:

```
^[\u0061-\u007A].+?$
```

And it *still* returned lines of all-caps text. Is there something outside of my brackets that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Is the "Match Case" checkbox checked?

Comment: Firstly - wow. No, it wasn't. Thanks, haha! But secondly, when I searched using the unicode for "a" through "z", it still returns all caps strings even with "Match Case" checked. If I literally type in "[A-Z][a-z]", though, it does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]` is an uppercase followed by lowercase... `[A-Za-z]` is upper- or lower-case

Answer (score 8):

As many other text editors, Notepad++ provides a global option to `Match case`. Even if your expression does not contain internal modifier `(?i)` the results can be unexpected depending on whether `Match case` is set ON or OFF.

So, your ALLCAPS lines are valid match for `^[A-Z][a-z].+?$` because the letters are matched in a case insensitive way when `Match case` is *OFF*.

**Check `Match case` to enable case sensitivity for regex search**:

[image]

**OTHER WAYS TO OVERRIDE CASE SENSITIVITY**

There are inline flags you may use with some regex flavors to hardcode  case sensitivity for all or part of the pattern:

- `(?-i)[A-Z][a-z]*` will only match an uppercase letter followed with lowercase ones as `(?-i)` turns the case sensitivity ON
- `(?i)[A-Z][a-z]*` will match 1 or more uppercase or lowercase letters
- `(?-i)[a-z](?i)[a-f](?-i)[a-z]` will match a lowercase letter, then a lower- or an uppercase letter from `a` to `f` and `A` to `F`, and then again will match a lowercase letter
- `S(?i:[a-z])S` - `S` or `s` will be matched with `S` (depends on the environment settings like `Match case`), then any upper- or lowercase letter and then `S`/`s`.